# Win32 function to get path to C:\ProgramData

Tags: winapi, path, programdata

My app needs to install some files that can be edited by the application at run time.  Install shield provides an alias [CommonAppDataFolder] that will resolve to c:\programData on Vista and Windows 7 and will also work on Windows XP.  Is there a win32 function that will return a similar path?

Maybe I need to call different functions depending on the operating system?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/`SHGetSpecialFolderPath` get you that, with `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` argument.

See code snippet here (at the bottom): [How to write a Windows XP Application that stores user and application data in the correct location by using Visual C++](https://web.archive.org/web/20190905002223/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310294/how-to-write-a-windows-xp-application-that-stores-user-and-application) ; the original link is no longer valid - code snippet is pulled below):

```
include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib")
void CreateTemporaryFile()
{
   TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
   // Get path for each computer, non-user specific and non-roaming data.
   if ( SUCCEEDED( SHGetFolderPath( NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, 
                                    NULL, 0, szPath ) ) )
   {
      TCHAR szTempFileName[MAX_PATH];
      // Append product-specific path - this path needs to already exist
      // for GetTempFileName to succeed.
      PathAppend( szPath, _T("\\My Company\\My Product\\1.0\\") );
      // Generate a temporary file name within this folder.
      if (GetTempFileName( szPath, 
                           _T("PRE"),
                           0,
                           szTempFileName ) != 0 )
      {
         HANDLE hFile = NULL;
         // Open the file.
         if (( hFile = CreateFile( szTempFileName, 
                                   GENERIC_WRITE, 
                                   0, 
                                   NULL, 
                                   CREATE_ALWAYS, 
                                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
                                   NULL )) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
         {
            // Write temporary data (code omitted).
            CloseHandle( hFile );
         }
      }
      else
          DWORD err = GetLastError();
   }
}
```

- Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data
- Windows Vista: C:\ProgramData
- Windows 7: C:\ProgramData

See also: [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It seems that CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA will resolve to: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data is there no way to get a path to c:\ProgramData?  Is this not a good place to store these kinds of files?

Comment: @Mike2012, both paths serve the same purpose - one on XP and below, and the other on Vista and above. So the result you get depend on the OS you use.

Comment: See above - added sample paths the constant resolves to in different Windows versions

Comment: Ah okay I see.  Confusion receding.  Thanks!

Comment: Code snippet broken unfortunately.

Comment: Holy crap that was fast. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Since Delphi **XE5**, this functionality is part of the framework.

- Unit: `System.IOUtils`
- Class: `TPath`
- Function: **`GetPublicPath`**

See [embarcadero docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetPublicPath) for further informations.