# Is there a difference in getting the executable path from `GetModuleFileName` vs `argv[0]` in windows

Tags: c++, windows

Working on windows in C++, I want to get the path of the executable file. I found 2 methods to do this, one, using simply `argv[0]` and one using `GetModuleFileName` from my tests, they give the same path. Is there any advantage of using `GetModuleFileName` over the simpler `argv[0]`?

My goal at the end is to create a log file located at the same folder and that will have the same name only with a `.log` extention.

This is my test program that gives the same result for both:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

std::string getCurrentExePathWithoutExtention()
{
    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    std::wstring ws(buffer);
    std::string fullPath(ws.begin(), ws.end());
    return fullPath;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string thisPath = getCurrentExePathWithoutExtention();
    cout << "This path: " << thisPath << endl;
    cout << "arg path:  " << argv[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are differences, but on windows it is recommended NOT to store files in the same folder as the executable but in a spefic program data folder. Reason the exe could be installed to a folder without write rights. See : [Win32 program data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196151/win32-function-to-get-path-to-c-programdata)

Comment: `argv[0]` is not guaranteed anywhere to be a full path, only a "name". The "name" can be empty, and it can even be a null pointer. Also read [this `main` function reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

Comment: @PepijnKramer And the same is very much true on most (all?) other operating systems, not just Windows.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, this is not an issue in this case, I know exactly where the file will be ran from. This is just a default setting, the user should provide their own log path, and this is just a fall back in case they don't. I will obviously check that file can be written to, in our setup it's ok to gracefully fail in case that the user was not using as intended, and probably preferable as if there is this problem, there are probably other additional problems.

Comment: @KonradRudolph good to know, however my knowledge on other OS-es is limited.

Comment: If the user has to provide a log path then don't fall back but ask for it when it is not present. Or end the program with a message that logging has to be configured. (Or is this for your own test convenience?)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sometimes `argv[0]` is part of command passed to the shell.. which gets interesting effects if shell uses aliases (afaik, that's even was employed for something, i.e. program got diffreent behaviour if it is running by alias). In generaldetermining location of executable on Posix-like is really.. messy, there are several fall-backs.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, those are the specification I got. And it isn't really critical in this sense, this is ran on our servers that should have writing permissions.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie There’s no platform-independent way but I am not aware of *any* UNIX-like platform where finding the current process’s path is difficult (except for the fact that a process does not need to have a corresponding binary path at all). In fact, many systems support procfs which makes this downright trivial. — Either way, relying on `arvg[0]` is not recommended on *any* system, since its value can be set arbitrarily by the parent process, and may not be related to the process at all.

Comment: @KonradRudolph problems arise from fact a) there can be hard links or symbol links used in path and "fake" path doesn't have permissions for program to be accessed b) that _some_ infrastructure, e.g. StartUp services may use `fork` and `spawn` directly for their purposes, not in same way as exec() does and even in case of `execve()` a program simply may not pass `argv[0]` correctly, c) passed path might incomplete, relative or non-canonical. There is also an option to look in `/proc`, try to subsititute  links for real paths, transform path to canonical form and then try to find executable

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Regarding (a) and (c): Generally, neither hard links nor symbolic links or relative paths are problems. They’re still valid, functioning paths. Regarding (b), yes, that’s what I alluded to when saying that `argv[0]` must not be relied on. — “There is also an option to look in `/proc`” — yes, I explicitly mentioned that, too.

Comment: To summarise my point: *if* the current process has a corresponding, available binary image on disk, finding a valid path for it is not hard. If that doesn’t exist (because the executable was loaded in a way that does not directly refer to a binary image on disk) that information is also readily available.

Comment: @KonradRudolph THey might be, if actions done with path later aren't compatible with links. let's say if path is `/bin/link-to-exe` pointing to `/opt/program/bin/exe` then `/bin/../data`  is not same as `/opt/program/data` (I know, fragile. but alot of real software is fragile.. even `accountservices`)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Sorry, I don’t agree that this is either (a) fragile or (b) a problem. Rather, this is a *well-defined and well-known* (and, as you say, very common) feature of symbolic links and obviously needs to be accounted for when modifying paths.

Comment: I'll not use `argv[0]`, I see that there is a higher chance of problems with it. Now, if either of you could just post a nice answer summarizing this, and maybe indicating if there are cases where `arvg[0]` is fine to use. So that I can accept it and we all move on.

Comment: GetModuleFileName() is reliable.  For argv[] you depend on the good graces of whatever app started your program, correctly invoking CreateProcess().  Doesn't always turn out well.